# Constructor in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constructor

I have created my iPhone apps but I have a problem.
I have a `classViewController` where I have implemented my program.
I must alloc 3 `NSMutableArray` but I don't want do it in grapich methods.
There isn't a constructor like Java for my class?

```
// I want put it in a method like constructor java

arrayPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
currentPositionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"noPosition"];
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, there is an initializer. It's called `-init`, and it goes a little something like this:

```
- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil) {
    // initializations go here.
  }
  return self;
}
```

**Edit:** Don't forget `-dealloc`, tho'.

```
- (void)dealloc {
  // release owned objects here
  [super dealloc]; // pretty important.
}
```

As a side note, using native language in code is generally a bad move, you usually want to stick to English, particularly when asking for help online and the like.

Comment: @Lohoris: This response was written before ARC was a thing. I'm guessing that with ARC you don't need `-dealloc` at all, but you might want to check the docs for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
/****************************************************************/
- (id) init 
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // All initializations you need
  }
  return self;
}
/******************** Another Constructor ********************************************/
- (id) initWithName: (NSString*) Name
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // All initializations, for example:
    _Name = Name;
  }
  return self;
}
/*************************** Another Constructor *************************************/
- (id) initWithName:(NSString*) Name AndAge: (int) Age
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // All initializations, for example:
    _Name = Name;
    _Age  =  Age;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: All inits should call classes designated initializer, you should only have one super init call.

Comment: Agree with @Firo, your `-init` should looks just like this: `return [self initWithName:nil andAge:0];` Or with any other appropriate default values.