# Constructor method not being called properly

Tags: objective-c, oop, object, constructor

I made a class called Player.h. The constructor is such:

```
-(Player*) construct
{
    health = 100;
    width = 50;
    height = 50;
    return self;
}
```

And it is in my header file as `-(Player*) construct;`

To verify I call my `getWidth` method and the other getters and all return as `0`
Is this the right way to make a constructor? I'm trying to incorporate better OOP practices and this is the first time in Obj-C I'm really using objects

Comment: In objective-c there are initializers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928404/constructor-in-objective-c

Comment: your method should not be called `getWidth`, but just `width`.  `get` is a prefix reserved for a very special role in Cocoa, and a generic getter is not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you create objects in Objective-C by way of calling alloc/init, in your case `[[Player alloc] init]`. Just overwrite the `init` method in your class - it already has the right skeleton. Do not remove the `self = [[super alloc] init]` line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your object to be constructed, you need to allocate in initialize it. While you can call your method `-construct`, it's traditionally called `-init` or `-initWith<Blah>` where `<Blah>` is some information like a rectangle or other useful value. You'd create an object like this:

```
Player* newPlayer = [[Player alloc] init];
```